# Editing live MSSQL Tables and Updating Fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking at creating a trigger on a live MS SQL spatial table that will update a field when a user either:

1. Creates a new feature
2. Updates the geometry of a feature.

Unfortunately I have only been able to work out updating a field when a new feature is created, or updating a field for every record when the geometry of a record is changed.

Ideal world - attribute 'Updated' populates current date for the particular feature that has been created or modified.

This is what I have so far that works only when creating a new feature:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER *[triggername]* 
ON  *[table]* 
AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(8)
SELECT @ID = [ID] FROM *[table]*
UPDATE *[table]*
   SET Updated = GETDATE()
   WHERE [ID] = @ID
END
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a basic trigger that will get fired when a record gets updated:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trg_MY_TABLE_OnUpdate
   ON dbo.MY_TABLE
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
Begin
   Update dbo.MY_TABLE
      Set   DATE_CHANGED = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            USER_CHANGED = SYSTEM_USER
      Where MI_PRINX In (Select MI_PRINX From inserted);
End
GO
```

and a similar one for a record being inserted

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trg_MY_TABLE_OnInsert
   ON dbo. MY_TABLE
AFTER INSERT
AS 
Begin
   Update dbo.MY_TABLE
      Set   DATE_CREATED = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            USER_CREATED = SYSTEM_USER
      Where MI_PRINX In (Select MI_PRINX From inserted);
End
GO
```

In the samples above I'm not checking whether the spatial object was edited or not. You can use the UPDATE() function to check whether a certain column has been changed, see more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx